# Powershell Script checks if service running and if not then stop and start it again

Tags: powershell, email, scripting

So i have this script that i can't figur out why it's not working.
The part I'm  having truble with is the "foreach" part befour the if sentence

```
var start
$email = "<Email1>, Email2"
$Service = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\TextFile.txt
Get-Content C:\temp\TextFile.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match $regex} | 
ForEach-Object {
var end

function FuncCheckService
{
param($Service)
$arrService = Get-Service |           #vvvv this is where im having truble
Where { $Service -contains $_.Name} | foreach {

if ($Service.Status -eq “Running”){
}

if ($Service.Status -ne “Running”){
    Stop-Service $Service
    # Wait for 20 seconds before starting the service
    Start-Service $Service
    FuncMail -To $email -From “$env:COMPUTERNAME@mercantec.dk” -Subject 
“SERVERNAME $env:COMPUTERNAME : Services not started.” -Body “Service $regex 
started” -smtpServer “SMTP Ip here”
}
}
}

function FuncMail {
#param($strTo, $strFrom, $strSubject, $strBody, $smtpServer)
param($To, $From, $Subject, $Body, $smtpServer)
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = $From
$msg.To.Add($To)
$msg.Subject = $Subject
$msg.IsBodyHtml = 1
$msg.Body = $Body 
$smtp.Send($msg)
}
FuncCheckService $Service
}
```

I'm open to any idea.

Comment: What isn't working? You have to be more specific.

Comment: the second foreach

Comment: @Shubub in what way is the second loop not working?

Comment: @Shubub: Edit the question and explain what is not working and if you are getting any error

Comment: `$service` is a string inside the function, `$service.Running` will always resolve to `$null`. That being said, it's extremely hard to help you without a description of _what you're trying to achieve_, and _how this current script fails your expectations_. Any odd behaviors and potential error messages (in full) should be included in your question as well

Answer (score 0):

i am new to powershell myself but from what you put on the header and looking at the script you want to get a list of services which are on a text file see if they are running if not then stop them wait for 20 seconds and then start the service. you also added some email function which sends you information.

here is a simple script that does the first bit

$content=Get-Content -Path C:\testing\service.txt

foreach ($item in $content) {

$getstatus=get-service -Name $item

if($getstatus.Status -eq 'stopped') {

stop-Service -Name $item

Start-Sleep -s 20

start-Service -Name $item
}

}